# getAttribLocation return always the same index

Tags: webgl

```
  attribute vec2 test; 
  attribute vec2 position;

  void main() {
    vTexCoord = position ; 
    vec2 gg = test;
    .....
  }
```

what stand getAttribLocation for ?
I used to believe it was the index of the attribute in the code,
but no, it always return 0 for position and 1 for test

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAttribLocation` gets the location of the attribute. Just because your GPU/driver returns `0` for `position` and `1` for `test` doesn't mean that all drivers will.

Also, while debugging it's common to comment out parts of a shader. If an attribute is not used the driver may optimize it away. In your case if you were to comment out whatever lines use `position` it's likely `test` would get location `0`. If you weren't looking up the location and you assumed `test` was always at location 1 your code would fail

On the other hand you can set the location *before you call `linkProgram`* by calling `bindAttribLocation`. For example

```
gl.bindAttribLocation(program, 10, "position");
gl.bindAttribLocation(program, 5, "test");
gl.linkProgram(program);
```

In which case you don't have to look up the locations.

```js
var vs = `
  attribute float position;
  attribute float test;
  
  void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, test, 0, 1);
  }
`;
var fs = `
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
  }
`;

function createShader(gl, type, source) {
  var s = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(s, source);
  gl.compileShader(s);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(s, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(s));
  }
  return s; 
}

var gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var prg = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(prg, createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vs));
gl.attachShader(prg, createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fs));
gl.bindAttribLocation(prg, 5, "position");
gl.bindAttribLocation(prg, 10, "test");
gl.linkProgram(prg);
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(prg, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(prg));
}
console.log("test location:", gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "test"));
console.log("position location:", gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "position"));
```

Comment: ok i did comment the line that use position, and now my test location return 0 ! So it make clear to me that getAttribLocation return location of the attribute. But now i did not understand why that value is the same with different shader ? 'afficheurShader.position  =  gl.getAttribLocation( afficheurShader  , "position" ); gridShader.position       =  gl.getAttribLocation( gridShader       , "position" ); how can i set the   gl.vertexAttribPointer( gridShader.position,....parameters... ); if the first argument is the same ? may be this initialisation must be in the moment i use the shader ?

Comment: i liked very much the way you explain the global machine of webgl with : gl = { arrayBuffer : somebuffer , ...etc...gl.bindBuffer= function(buffer)....etc...but please, what about gl.useProgram(shader) ? is "shader" a global variable ?

Comment: attributes are global state. You set them up for one program, then run that program (calling drawXXX). You then set them up for a different program and then run that program etc...  You can have multiple programs therefore in `gl.useProgram(someProgram)` the `someProgram` is not global state but calling `gl.useProgram` makes `someProgram` the *current program*. There is only ever one program that's *current*. It's the last one you passed to `gl.useProgram`.